# Many to Many, Through Relationship for Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

On Rails 4, I am using devise for my users and I have a scaffold for exercises.

Each user is to have many exercises, and each exercises have many users, this is done through a model called schedule.

I want to build a form, so that when a new exercise is created then it can be assigned to the Users. I am little lost on how to allow the schedule table to accept both the exercise_id and user_id when I create a new exercise. Any help is appreciated!

/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :schedules
has_many :exercises, :through => :schedules
```

/exercise.rb

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :description, presence: true

has_many :schedules
has_many :users, :through => :schedules
```

/schedules.rb

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :exercise
belongs_to :user
```

Exercise Controller

```
def exercise_params
  params.require(:exercise).permit(:description, :notes, :video, {:users=>[]})


end
```

**edit**

I am lost as what to do next in order to get the Schedule table to populate with Exercise_ids and User_ids.

Schema:

USERS
id
email
name
(standard columns from devise)

EXERCISES
id
description
created_at
updated_at
tag
notes
video_file_name
video_content_type
video_file_size
video_updated_at

SCHEDULE
id
exercise_id
user_id
position
created_at
updated_at

Comment: can you post your schema? I do not understand your question.. do you have problems with permitting the params? Or what is your question?

Comment: I think you need to use accepts_attributes_for :users in your Excercise model and then use a fields_for block for assigning users to an excersice. Then you can permit the users_attributes array in the params.